# Page not "mobile friendly" because style sheets won't load properly, what can I do?

Tags: mobile, mobile-friendly-tool, mobile-first-index

I've just tested my website against google's [mobile friendliness tester tool](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly), and it shows that the page is not mobile friendly.

That's because in that tester tool, the CSS files are not loading, and the page effectively looks pretty bad.

**I've checked in a couple of real phones with 4G and 3G connections and everything is ok.** Then, why is that happening at Google's tool and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

This is how the page looks for the tool
[image: Page not "mobile friendly" because css files won't load properly]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cause for this problem is that Googlebot can't read the style sheets even though users can read them. Check to make sure that your robots.txt file doesn't disallow your style sheets.

[Since a 2014 announcement](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html), Google has requested that CSS and JavaScript be crawlable, so that Googlebot can render your pages.